# Lumen - Using factory() function in tests make error - Undefined Function

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, tdd, lumen

I'm using Lumen 8.3 ,wanted to use `factory()` function in my tests, it gives me
`Undefined Function` ,there is nothing useful in the [Docs of Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/testing#model-factories)

Am i missing something here?

```
class ProductTest extends TestCase
{

    public function test_if_can_send_products_list(){
        $products = factory('App/Products',5)->make();
        $this->json('post','/payouts',$products)
        ->seeJson([
            'created' => true,
        ]);

    }
}
```

->

`Error: Call to undefined function factory()`

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use direct class like that:

```
$products = factory(Products::class, 5)->create();
```

don't forget to add `Products` model usage (namespace).

**Edit**

You should create Factory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Products;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Products::class;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->unique()->userName()
        ];
    }
}
```

And add `HasFactory` Trait to your model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
class Products extends Model {
   use HasFactory;
}
```

you can also use it like this

```
Products::factory()->count(5)->make();
```

Comment: tnx , i already have that factory class for my model .

but `factory()` function is not working.
used the trait you mentioned (HasFactory) but no help, even my IDE is warning me about not defined function.

 ( the `factory` function is actually included in HasFactory trait but don't know why it is giving me undefined)

Comment: did you tried to use this: `Products::factory()->count(5)->make();`
what was the output ?

Comment: Missed it sorry , yeah it is going to work , but why something that is mentioned in lumen docs , is not working ?

Comment: I wait for the exact answer about this `factory()` function. thank you for the time <3

Answer (score 0):

I just uncommented these lines in `app.php` file

```
$app->withFacades();

$app->withEloquent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Laravel 8 removed the 'factory' helper, and it seems Lumen followed that path without updating documentation;
@Faesal Answer is the correct way to do it these days;
remember to add `use HasFactory;` to your Model.